# Is $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ an ideal of $C(\mathbb{R}) ?$ True/false

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following statement true/false ?

> Let $C(\mathbb R)$ denote the ring of all continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb R$, with the operations of pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication. Then the set of all continuous functions with compact support form an ideal in this ring

**My attempt**:  I think  this statement is  false.

Let $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ denote the  set  of all continious  function  with  compact support .

Let  $f  \in C_c(\mathbb{R}) \implies{\rm Supp}f= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}  : f \neq  0\}$ and $r(x)= 0 \in C(\mathbb{R})$

Then ${\rm Supp}(f\cdot r)= \{x  \in \mathbb{R} : f\cdot r =0\} \notin C_c(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: If the support of $f$ is the compact set $K,$ and you define $r(x)=0,$ then the support of $rf$ is empty [support = closure of set where function is nonzero.] And the empty set is compact. So you do not have a counterexample.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? The support is not supposed to be in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, it's not a function. $fr$ is the function here. The support of the zero function is clearly empty, and so compact. By the way, are you sure the support is defined as you wrote it? Usually it is defined to be the closure of $\{x: f(x)\ne 0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ has compact support, and $g \in C(\mathbb{R})$ is arbitrary, then the set where $fg = gf$ is non-zero, is a subset of the compact support of $f$ and is hence also bounded. Which implies that $fg = gf$ has compact support. In your case, $fr = 0$ has compact support as well, since the support is empty, and the empty set is closed and bounded and hence compact.

You also need to check that $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup for the group $C(\mathbb{R}),+$. (Should be doable.)